# Problema con peticiones a la API de Twitter y almacenar las respuestas en una lista

Tags: python, api, while, twitter, twitter-api

Soy nuevo en esto y estoy realizando un ejercicio donde tengo que realizar una serie de peticiones a la API de Twitter basadas en un #. El problema es que solo se pueden realizar peticiones de 100 en 100 con la versión gratuita de la API, y tengo que llegar a 1000 Tweets **(tweet_query_size)**. Para esto estoy utilizando un **while** que pretendo que siga acumulando los ids de los tweets de 100 en 100 hasta llegar a 1000 en **tweet_list_ids**, en esta lista ya había almacenados 12 ids anteriores, y con este while guarda los 100 siguientes pero no sigue con el bucle. A su vez hay una función, **wait_for_awhile**, que hace esperar al bucle el tiempo necesario para que la API vuelva a dejarte hacer peticiones. No se si me estoy explicando bien, y al estar siguiendo un ejercicio me está siendo bastante complicado, dejo aquí el trozo de código donde me está dando el problema, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
while (len(tweet_list_ids) < tweet_query_size):
try:
    print("Tweets %s to %s: cursor: %s" %
         (len(tweet_list_ids), len(tweet_list_ids) + 100, next_max_id))
    
    #No especificamos le type_result para que busque solo los más recientes.
    result = twitter.search(q='#Secret2N', count = 100, max_id=next_max_id)
    
    csvfile = open('tweet_list.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    
    for tw in result['statuses']:
        if (first_time == True):
            first_time = False
            next_max_id = tw['id']
        if tw['id'] not in tweet_list_ids:
            tweet_list_ids.append(tw['id'])
            retweet = False
            retweet_user = 'NA'
            mention = 'NA'
            if 'retweeted_status' in tw:
                retweet = True
                retweet_user = tw['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name']
            if (len(tw['entities']['user_mentions']) == 0):
                writer.writerow([tw['user']['screen_name'],
                                 tw['user']['id'],
                                 tw['user']['followers_count'],
                                 tw['id'], tw['in_reply_to_screen_name'],
                                 retweet,
                                 retweet_user,
                                 'NA',
                                 tw['text'].encode('utf-8').strip(),
                                 tw['created_at']])
            else:
                for mention in tw['entities']['user_mentions']:
                    writer.writerow([tw['user']['screen_name'],
                                     tw['user']['id'],
                                     tw['user']['followers_count'],
                                     tw['id'],
                                     tw['in_reply_to_screen_name'],
                                     retweet,
                                     retweet_user,
                                     mention['screen_name'],
                                     tw['text'].encode('utf-8').strip(),
                                     tw['created_at']])

    #cerramos el csv:
    csvfile.close()
    
except TwythonRateLimitError as e:
    wait_for_awhile()
except:
    print("FAILED: Unexpected error", sys.exc_info()[0])
    pass
```

Lo que obtengo al ejecutar el código es lo siguiente:

```
Tweets 12 to 112: cursor: -1
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
Tweets 112 to 212: cursor: 1455680340891250690
.
.
.
```

Y se sigue así infinitamente.

Comment: Hola selek31, un consejo: no uses try/except para encapsular tanto código, solo el estrictamente necesario. Por ejemplo encapsula únicamente el query y deja fuera el resto de lógica. Si ya sabes cuál es el limite no esperes sobrepasarlo y si tu código para el csv está bien escrito no necesitas el try. También encapsularia el `writer` en otro try/except (en caso de que no exista el archivo) y estaría bien que aprendieras a usar los context managers (se vuelve más intuitivo y menos susceptible a bugs)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @JoseRodriguez, voy a tratar de seguir tus consejos aunque al ser tan nuevo en esto, hay conceptos que se me escapan, ya que aún no tengo interiorizado el funcionamiento de todo esto, y tardo bastante en verle la lógica todo el código. Pero de igual manera muchísimas gracias.

Comment: No pasa nada, todos hemos empezado de cero. Como norma general intenta "separar" las tareas de tu código; así es más sencillo acotar la búsqueda de un bug. Tampoco es buena idea referenciar variables antes de inicializarlas (por eso el primer print lo tienes bugeado, en el primer ciclo imprimes primero los valores y luego actualizas el valor y debería ser siempre al revés). Ya lo irás pillando a base de errores y depuración.